# Can I use "et al" when addressing people?

Tags: word-choice

Say Alice sends me an email, with a few other people in the cc list. When I reply-all the email but with the emphasis that it is mainly for Alice's attention, can I say the following?

> "Hi Alice, et al"

Comment: I see no reason why it couldn't be used in the right *specific* context. For instance, if Alice and the other were all bibliographers. (Or academics or other people in a field used to the terminology being used in the back matter of books.) Any group of bibliographers would  likely chuckle at being addressed that way. But I wouldn't recommend that form of address *in general*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent and received many such emails over almost 20 years, and "et al" was never to be seen.

---

One of the most usual ways to do it is:

> Hello Alice,
>
> Hello everyone,
>
> Please be informed that...

If the message needs to be customized for the different audiences, you might use:

> Hello everyone,
>
> Please find attached...
>
> @Paul:
>
> Thank you for your support...
>
> @ Alice:
>
> Please remember to ...

Comment: Additionally:   “Et al.” — which is short for “et alia” — is Latin and is almost never used in spoken English, unless you are reading words that are written on a page.